# How do I set div height proportional to screen resolution?

Tags: css, height

I saw there are many similar questions, but I can't find one solution working for me.

My page has this structure:

```
    <body>
    <div id="whole_page">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main"> 
           <div id="img_container"></div>
           <div id="img_container"></div>
           <div id="img_container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

My css is:

```
html,body{
    height:100%; width:100%;
    padding-top:50px;
}

#whole_page{
    height:calc(100%-50px); width:100%;
}

#header{
    position:fixed;
    height:50px; // header 
}

#image_container{
    width:100%;
    height:30%;
}
```

I want to set "main" 's height to 100% (window height) minus header height (50px).
Further, I want each div with id "image_container" to be 30% of the "main" div and large 100% of widonws width. So that I have approximately 3 of those div in the page, before needing to scroll.

The problem is that % seem to not work at all. As I didn't write them (tried with Chrome's dev tools).

Actually I am using bootstrap to fill content of header/main but as far as I know this shouldn't give problems with height.

Any clue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check `calc()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key problem is that you did not change the height of #main. You also had a miss type between your CSS and HTML, in your CSS you referred to #image_container while in your HTML you used 'id="img_container"'. I change both CSS and HTML to '.img_container' and 'class="img_container"' respectively. I also noticed that you had twice the amount of space at the top than the size needed for your #header since 'padding-top: 50px;' was applied to html and body.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="whole_page">
    <div id="header" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="img_container" style="background-color: red;"></div>
        <div class="img_container" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
        <div class="img_container" style="background-color: green;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top:50px;
}
#whole_page {
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    width: 100%;
}
#header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#main {
    height: 100%;
}
.img_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
}
```

PS - add color to some of the tags so I could see them. You can just delete the style attribute from the '#header' and '.img_container' tags.

EDIT - Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xiondark2008/DJJ2d/

EDIT2 - Just side thought, 'height: calc(100%-50px);' is an invalid property, at least in chrome, however 'height: calc(100% - 50px);' **is** a valid property, again, at least in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box` and `padding`..

http://jsfiddle.net/jVkL6/

Comment: thank for your suggestion. However I just edited your jsfiddle by setting a background color to each "images_container" but it doesn't work as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/jVkL6/4/

Comment: You named your css class `img_container` but in your css you use `image_container`. Also you need all parents to have a height (`.main`) needs: http://jsfiddle.net/jVkL6/5/